# How can I update XLSX sheet through SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xlsx

I have a connection from SQL (via Linked server) to my XLSx file.

It works just fine if I use XLS file just for reading purpose (`select * ...`).

But is it possible to update XLS sheet from a SQL? And how?

This is my case:

```
<https://www.screencast.com/t/M39Nu3dxuCIF>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Which DBMS you are using. SQL Server?

Comment: it seems sql-server from screenshot you using SSMS.

Comment: I am using: SQL server Managenent Studio v 17.9

Comment: database (xls) file is in new xlsx format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across with that problem previously. I have fixed it using `OPENROWSET()`

Here is sample :

```
UPDATE OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0',
 'Excel 12.0;DATABASE=<Your File Location\<your file name>.xls>',
 'SELECT * from [KATALOGSIHR$] ')
 SET KatalogSI=2
 WHERE SAP='18864'
```